# does there exist "valde <superlative>"?

Tags: vocabulary, example-request, superlatives

Are there any examples in classical texts where the word 'valde' is used before a superlative? For example 'valde stultissimus' to mean very, very stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Georges’s Dictionary has references for valde optimus and valde summus from Pliny and Valerius.

http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/valde

Answer (score 7):

No, valde can at most take a comparative adjective, not a superlative. However, "vel" can be used in your case. "vel" + a superlative is common in Latin literature, for example in Cicero's Pro Roscio Amerino:

> vel potentissimus ... L. Cornelius Chrysogonus